# Rails - Param is missing or the value is empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, pickadate

Lately, I've connected [pickadate](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) gem. Now my `_form` looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@event, :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
<%= render('error_message') %>

<div class="field form-group">
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
</div>

<div class="field form-group">
  <%= f.label :start_time %>
  <%= f.text_field :start_time, class: "datepicker form-control"%>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit 'Save', class: "btn btn-success" %>
</div>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({
        //customization
    })
</script>
```

Here is `new.html.erb`:

```
<% provide(:title, t('new_event_title')) %>

<h1><%= t('new_event_h1') %></h1>

<%= render 'form' %>
```

As you see, `Event` model has 2 parameters: `name` (string type) and `start_time` (datetime type). Here is my `create` method and `event_params`:

```
def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    redirect_to events_path
end

def event_params
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :start_time)
end
```

But, by clicking 'Save' button I've got the following error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in EventsController#create
    param is missing or the value is empty: event
```

Here is the server log:

```
Started POST "/events" for ::1 at 2016-03-07 15:23:08 +0300
Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
{"controller"=>"events", "action"=>"create"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

My rendered _form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="new_event" action="/events" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="jvg+<...>Q==" />


<div class="field form-group">
  <label for="event_name">Name</label><br>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="event[name]" id="event_name" />
</div>

<div class="field form-group">
  <label for="event_start_time">Start time</label><br>
  <input class="datepicker form-control" type="text" name="event[start_time]" id="event_start_time" />
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
</div>
</form>
```

Something wrong with form I guess. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: try to print the params you received in the `create` action using `puts params` and post it.

Comment: @GokulM I've added the line but where should I look for the result. Server console? There is nothing there

Comment: Yeah it should print the `params` in your server console.. `def create
    puts event_params                                                                                                            @event = Event.new(event_params)
    redirect_to events_path
end
` or just use `puts params`

Comment: @GokulM Found it: `{"controller"=>"events", "action"=>"create"}`

Comment: hey, there is no `params` received for `create` thats why you got the error `param is missing or the value is empty: event`

Comment: @GokulM Strange... Any ideas why?

Comment: @SergaRUS - Could you paste your form html after it is being rendered?

Comment: @BroiSatse I've added it to the question

Comment: try removing the braces, `<%= form_for @event, as: :post, url: events_path, html: { class: "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>`

Comment: @Sravan the same result :(

Comment: paste some more server log, which comes above the one which you pasted

Comment: @Sravan added to the question

Comment: thats the issue, go to application controller and comment the line protect from forgery.

Comment: @Sravan I've commented it, but nothing changes. Only some new logs pointing the db queries

Comment: @Sravan - It is like saying, "hey, my key is broken. I am gona remove all the locks"

Comment: @SergaRUS - How do you render your form? Could you show your edit template (assuming you render _form partial there)?

Comment: the issue definitly seems to be in crsf token, in your events controller at the top add this line `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token`  and uncomment that line in application controller, which you commented out.

Comment: @Sravan - Again, there is a reason why rails check authenticity token, removing it is a serious security risk.

Comment: @Sravan Nothing changes

Comment: @SergaRUS - Do you have `csrf_meta_tags` in your layout?